# selenium find specific argument python

Tags: python, selenium, find

Hei there

I'm trying to automatically push a button, but I don't seem to find the right location with Selenium selectors. It's the one nested and called 'submit'. What do I do?

```
<button class="pull-right" type="submit"><span>Resultate anzeigen</span></button>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What selectors have you tried? Can you show us some code?

Comment: driver.find_element_by_class_name('pull-right'), didn't react to that, apparently there is another similar one, but with another 'type', and I also tried: driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type_'submit]")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this xpath.
//button[@class='pull-right']//span[contains(text(), 'Resultate')]

Comment: Now It worked, Copied the xpath via firefox inspector. Thanks!